# What happens when a new object is created using another (existing) object?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, copy-constructor

I read in a book, it says:
when we initialize a newly created object using another - uses copy constructor to create a temporary object and then uses assignment operator to copy values to the new object!

And later in the book I read:
When a new object is initialized using another object, compiler creates a temporary object which is copied to the new object using copy constructor. The temporary object is passed as an argument to the copy constructor.

Really confused, what actually happens!!

Comment: Continue the reading and come back to this point later, sure you will understand it then ;)

Comment: @FirstStep No, the first statement sounds wrong. The second could be correct. The "temporary" may never happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ how does copy constructor work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053602/c-how-does-copy-constructor-work)

Comment: @Juan I did not say which is correct. But both are statementing the same information.. I might be the only one that sees both are same

Comment: They both sound wrong to we.  I do not see why a temporary would be made when copy constructing an object with another object of the same type.  I also fail to see where assignment comes into the first example.

Comment: @FirstStep No, they don't. If they did, then both would be correct or incorrect.

Comment: @juan the fact that both are incorrect _or_  both are correct, should not confuse the OP then..

Comment: @FirstStep No, you are confused. You're the one who thinks both statements have the same information.

Comment: @juwan .. Maybe.. I need to recktify? rectify? whatever it is.. I need sort my self* together then. But if I say "_Hey I read X = A here and read X = B there.. Why and I am confused_".. Does not sound the same as "_Hey I read X = A here and X = A there, is this correct or incorrect?_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think either of these statements is correct - the copy-assignment operator is not called.

I would describe what happens as:

When you **create** a new object as a copy of an existing object, then the copy constructor is called:

```
// creation of new objects
Test t2(t1);
Test t3 = t1;
```

Only when you **assign to an already existing object** does the copy-assignment operator get called

```
// assign to already existing variable
Test t4;
t4 = t1;
```

We can prove this with the following little example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;
    Test(const Test &t)
    {
        std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
    }
    Test& operator= (const Test &t)
    {
        std::cout << "copy assignment operator\n";
       return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t1;

    // both of these will only call the copy constructor
    Test t2(t1);
    Test t3 = t1;

    // only when assigning to an already existing variable is the copy-assignment operator called
    Test t4;
    t4 = t1;

    // prevent unused variable warnings
    (void)t2;
    (void)t3;
    (void)t4;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> copy constructor
> copy constructor
> copy assignment operator
> ```

[working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b9ee8baa56081da)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the example. I understood this point, but the above statements confused me that if both copy constructor and overloaded assignment operator, both are being used during initialization of an object from an existing one.

Comment: @winter I think the statements you mentioned are incorrect. What book did you find them in?