# C++ How to create a new object while assigning it to another

Tags: c++, oop

I want to transform this C# code into C++ :

```
list.head = new LinkedListNode("head node data");
```

How can i do this in C++ with one line, i dont want to do this:

```
LinkedListNode headnode("head node data");
list.head = headnode;
```

Comment: If that C++ code compiles, why not just do `list.head = LinkedListNode("head node data");`?

Comment: Thanks for answering i have another issue with read access error should i open a new title

Comment: Sure, but be sure to include a [mcve]. It's hard to answer questions properly when we have to guess how things are declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c++, you would do:

```
list.head = new LinkedListNode("head node data");
```

assuming `list.head` is of type `LinkedListNode*`.

If `list.head` is of type `LinkedListNode`, then you can simply do:

```
list.head = LinkedListNode("head node data");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering i have another issue with read access error should i open a new title

Answer (score 0):

I think this post is similar to your purpose.

[What happens when a new object is created using another (existing) object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975574/what-happens-when-a-new-object-is-created-using-another-existing-object)

Tell me if it work.