# Different ways of constructing a object using another object

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, copy-constructor

A few days ago I read this article: [Constructor of type int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350125/constructor-of-type-int)

But I think I have to clarify something first.

Suppose I have a class `Myclass` and I already created an object `obj1`.

Are there differences between writing:

```
Myclass obj2(obj1);
```

and

```
Myclass obj2 = obj1;
```

?

Like this article said: [What happens when a new object is created using another (existing) object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975574/what-happens-when-a-new-object-is-created-using-another-existing-object).

Is there a temporary object created to be assigned to the newly created object? Is the copy constructor invoked to create that temporary object? Then the newly created object is constructed by what?

I am confused.

I think this question must have been asked before. But I just couldn't find one using the keywords I can come up with.

Comment: No difference if both compile (which is how it's usually are). The second form doesn't allow `explicit` constructors, but nobody usually makes copy constructors explicit.

Comment: See dupe: [Is there a difference between copy-initialization and direct-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051468/12002570)

Answer (score 2):

From a strict point of view,

```
Myclass obj2(obj1);
```

will be a [*direct initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization).

While

```
Myclass obj2 = obj1;
```

will be a [*copy initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

However, the effect of both will be the exact same: The `Myclass` copy-constructor being invoked.